# Where to put drawables when developing for multiple screens?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, android-drawable

I am developing for multiple screens, so my layouts are in layout, layout-large, layout-xlarge. The button background for these layouts has been posted in drawable-hdpi, drawable-xgdpi, drawable-xxhdpi folders.

But, when I run the application, it seems like the layouts are selecting the most smallest drawables available. xhdpi is not using the correctly sized image. Why is this? Do I need to create a separate structure of drawable folders?

Comment: It depends on pixel density of the device you are using. check the developer pixel density doc with your device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// try this way
                            ldpi    mdpi    hdpi    xhdpi   xxhdpi    xxxhdpi
Launcher And Home           36      48      72      96      144       192
Tab,Dialog and List         24      32      48      64      96        128
Action Bar And Status Bar   18      24      36      48      72        96
Background                  320*426 320*470 480*640 720*960 1080*1920 1080*1920
```

Comment: ahh, This is great. I am keeping this as a reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you should follow the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio between the four generalized densities.
For example, if you have a bitmap drawable that's 48x48 pixels for medium-density screen
(the size for a launcher icon), all the different sizes should be:

```
36x36 for low-density
48x48 for medium-density
72x72 for high-density
96x96 for extra high-density
```

Please take overview of this Link : [Android Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation,

Since Android runs in devices with a wide variety of screen densities, you should always provide your bitmap resources tailored to each of the generalized density buckets: low, medium, high and extra-high density. This will help you achieve good graphical quality and performance on all screen densities.

To generate these images, you should start with your raw resource in vector format and generate the images for each density using the following size scale:

```
xhdpi: 2.0
hdpi: 1.5
mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
ldpi: 0.75
```

This means that if you generate a 200x200 image for xhdpi devices, you should generate the same resource in 150x150 for hdpi, 100x100 for mdpi and finally a 75x75 image for ldpi devices.

Then, place the generated image files in the appropriate subdirectory under res/ and the system will pick the correct one automatically based on the screen density of the device your application is running on:

```
MyProject/
  res/
    drawable-xhdpi/
        awesomeimage.png
    drawable-hdpi/
        awesomeimage.png
    drawable-mdpi/
        awesomeimage.png
    drawable-ldpi/
        awesomeimage.png
```

Then, any time you reference @drawable/awesomeimage, the system selects the appropriate bitmap based on the screen's dpi. refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

Answer (score 1):

Useful link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Android automatically select which one to use. And smaller one is prefer. Make sure that you put drawable in the right dpi-folder. So the larger on should be put on drawable-xxhdpi, the lowest should be in drawable-ldpi.